# Actualizar videos en android studio

Tags: android-studio

actualmente estoy desarrollando una app de videos en streaming, quisiera saber como puedo implementar un código para poder actualizar el catalogo de películas y series solo con la conexión a internet.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.